# Remote Notifications in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, ios10

So we all know that Apple has introduced the UserNotifications Framework this summer and it's great.
And according to Apple's API references and a WWDC Session about this framework, we now have a new way to register for push notification as follows:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [options], completionHandler: {})
```

But clearly this method is not gonna get a deviceToken from the APNs server so Apple has kept some of the API in the UIKit as follows:

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data){}
```

That's the two method for registering and getting the deviceToken for Remote Notifications.

So it's getting ambiguous that if I only want to register for Remote Notifications will I still have to do the `requestAuthorization` thing? Or is the `requestAuthorization` just for Registering Local Notifications?

Plus if I need to implement both of them even if I only want to register for Remote Notifications, where should I write the `registerForRemoteNotifications()`? Should I write it in the `completionHandler` in `requestAuthorization` or should I just write it outside as if this two `request` and `register` thing are running in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to register for remote notifications, you still need to `requestAuthorization`, because this is how you ask the user if you may display alerts and sounds, which applies to both local and remote notifications.

You can call `registerForRemoteNotifications` outside of your `requestAuthorization` completion handler and allow them to run in parallel.

**Update:**

`registerForRemoteNotifications` gets you the user's token *whether or not* they've approved push notifications.

**How is this useful if the user declined?**

At any time in the future (after your app has called `requestAuthorization` to indicate that it would like to send notifications), the user can go into the Settings app, tap your app, and turn on the Allow Notifications setting.

If you are already sending notifications using the user's token, those notifications will begin coming through when the user turns on permission, without any action needed from you.

Comment: I'm just really confused that this isn't logically clear, I mean, the way we implement the code. Like, if inside  completion handler I found out that `granted == false` which means the users declined the app's request for notification, what is the point for us to still do `registerForRemoteNotifications` in parallel then?

Comment: Just did some tests in my app so I can update my answer. I agree the documentation is extremely unclear.

Comment: Guess Apple just needs to improve it.